# How to click on the Delete icon as per the ID given in excel through selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am having a page with table containing details of the users, i want to click on delete icon upon the ID retrieving from the excel.Selenium Webdriver and java is used for doing the same.
I am using this code to retrieve name from excel:-

```
data.getPatientID().get(rowCnt);
```

HTML code of the table :-

```
<tr class="rgRow" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridUserControl1_RadGrid1_ctl00__0">
<td>PAT 033</td>
<td><a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridUserControl1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_lbtnLastname" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridUserControl1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$lbtnLastname','')">Bee</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>Barry</td>
<td>(833)833-8338</td>
<td>Frisco</td>
<td>physician new </td>
<td><a onclick="if(!confirm('Do you want to delete this record'))return false;" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridUserControl1_RadGrid1_ctl00_ctl04_Remove" class="closeBtn" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GridUserControl1$RadGrid1$ctl00$ctl04$Remove','')"></a></td>
```

Any help will be appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5uBy.png)

The text in **** is name and delete button.

Comment: share your html code for delete button and name which is in table.

Comment: where is delete button in this code ?

Comment: and which one is name "Davis tinku" ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the HTML you have shared, there is only one clickable link with name **Albert**.

You can use **linkText** in this case :

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Albert")).click()
```

Note that there is no delete button.

Comment: I have delete icon at end of table. please see the  screenshot attached.

Comment: I have checked your updated HTML and I don't see any delete button. Please share HTML table with at least full one row which will contain name and respective delete button.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to click on *delete icon* you can create a function which will take an argument as the *name* e.g. **Albert** and click on the respective *delete icon* as follows:

```
public void clickDeleteIcon(String fname)
{
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//tr[@class='rgRow'][contains(@id,'_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridUserControl1_RadGrid1_')]//following::td[2]/a[.='" + fname + "']//following::a[1]"))).click();
}
```

Now to click on *delete icon* you can call the function `clickDeleteIcon(String fname)` passing any of the *names* as follows:

```
clickDeleteIcon("Albert");
//or
clickDeleteIcon("Bee")
```

Comment: @ReshmiAneesh Please try the updated code and let me know the status

Comment: It is not working for name, i think we need to check using the ID <td>PAT 033</td> as it is unique.

Comment: @ReshmiAneesh Please try the updated code and let me know the status

Comment: it wont work for name.. as there will be more than users with same name.. i think it is the fault occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the approach to click on Delete is to apply wait on condition which ever is applicable in your case if it is not name.